# Finding parameters of a linear programming problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, integer-programming, simplex-method

I have the following programming problem:

> $\min c_1x_1+c_2x_2$  such that $$x_2 \leq x_1$$$$x_1 \leq 2x_2+2$$$$x_1, x_2 \geq 0$$

How do I show that this problem is feasible and how do i find the condition of $c_1$ and $c_2$ so that the given problem has a finite optimal value using the dual problem?

Can I just set $x_1, x_2=0$ to show feasibility?

And also I the dual is as follows:

> $\max 2y_2$  such that $$-y_1+y_2 \geq c_1$$ $$y_1-2y_2 \geq c_2$$$$c_1, c_2 \geq 0$$

Comment: Feasibility just means the constraint set is non empty, and since $x_1=0, x_2=0$ is feasible the constraint set is not empty. So yes.

Comment: It might help to draw a little picture of the feasible set to answer your question about $c_1,c_2$.

Comment: @copper.hat so i plotted the constraints on desmos, and it seems like the only feasible solution where both $c_1, c_2 \geq 0$ satisfied is at 0. Is this the right answer? However, how do I do this mathematicallu (as in without a picture)

Comment: You have a small typo: Your $c_{1}, c_{2} \geq 0$ constraints should be $y_{1}, y_{2} \geq 0$ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strong duality holds whenever the primal has an optimal solution, i.e. the problem is not infeasible and its minimum is not $-\infty$.

Consider the plot of the boundaries of your primal problem's feasible region.

[image]

I've omitted the shading of the inequalities, but if you can convince yourself that the feasible region is one of the bounded triangles, then all choices of $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ will give the same primal and dual solution because the feasible region is bounded and nonempty. In other words, no additional conditions are required on $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$.

If, on the other hand, the feasible region is another section of the plot, then you have an unbounded solution for some choices of $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$. Namely, those values of $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ which take the objective value to $-\infty$ cause an issue. See if you can reason which $c$ values give you problems from the geometry of the picture.

And yes, to check feasibility it suffices to note that $x_1 = 0$, $x_{2} = 0$ is feasible.

Comment: The 2 boundaries for the Primal aren't parallel though? Or am I doing a stupid mistake here? They intersect at $(-2, -2)$,

Comment: You're right. I had a small typo in my plotting code. Please see edit.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I find $c_1$ and $c_2$ that gives a finite optimal solution? I don't understand where the duality comes in play.

Comment: You need to find values of $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ such that the objective function cannot be taken off to $-\infty$. Reasoning from the picture, you should be able to convince yourself that the middle region within the upper right quadrant is your feasible region. Any $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$ values such that $\langle (c_{1}, c_{2}), (1,1) \rangle < 0$ or $\langle (c_{1}, c_{2}), (1,1/2) \rangle < 0$ will cause an issue, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the usual dot product.

Comment: What's the reasoning for the dot product? And why did we use $(1,1)$ and $(1, \frac{1}{2})$? Sorry for the extensive questions, I'm fairly new to this topic :(

Comment: They come from the equations defining the boundaries of the feasible regions. Alternatively (and equivalently by duality), you can choose $c$ values which gives a nonempty feasible region of the dual.

Comment: Okay, I plotted the dual and the only possible value for $c_1$ and $c_2$ is $0$ if both are to be positive. Is this the solution?

Comment: No. If you plot the dual you get the same answer as in my comment above. When you plot the boundary lines in the dual region, note that $c_{2}/2 + c_{1} \geq 0$ is required for the boundary to be nonempty because of the shading of the lines. Then note that this shaded region between the lines is infeasible with respect to the $y_{1}, y_{2} \geq 0$ constraint unless $c_{1} + c_{2} \geq 0$.